# Como posso deixar o eixo Y personalizado

Tags: r, gráfico, plot, series-temporais

Como posso deixar o eixo `Y` personalizado. Por ex: 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 15 e 30.
De forma que eu possa visualizar melhor as variáveis com valores próximos.

```
a=c(2015:2018)
ost=c(29.33,22.72,24.52,27.83)
snc=c(11.17,15.29,10.64,6.94)
olh=c(4.89,4.16,7.40,6.25)
card=c(4.66,5.09,7.17,3.24)
fend=c(3.26,5.09,5.09,4.16)
gen=c(3.03,4.86,3.70,2.78)
dig=c(1.86,4.63,3.47,2.54)
out=c(2.79,1.39,2.78,2.08)
crom=c(3.26,1.16,3.01,1.39)
resp=c(1.16,0.0,0.93,0.69)
uri=c(0.47,0.93,0.23,0.69)


plot( ost ~a , type="o" , lty=1 , xlab="Ano" , ylab="Tipo" , col=("18") , lwd=3 , pch=20, ylim=c(0,29),xaxt ="n") 
lines(snc ~a , col="#f4511e" ,lty=1, lwd=3, pch=20 , type="o" )
lines(olh ~a , col="#a1887f" ,lty=1, lwd=3 , pch=20 , type="o" )
lines(card ~a , col="#bc5100" ,lty=1, lwd=3 , pch=20 , type="o" )
lines(fend ~a , col="#ffd95a" ,lty=1, lwd=3 , pch=20 , type="o" )
lines(gen ~a , col="#00701a" ,lty=1, lwd=3 , pch=20 , type="o" )
lines(dig ~a , col="#0069c0" ,lty=1, lwd=3 , pch=20 , type="o" )
lines(out ~a , col="#e91e63" ,lty=1, lwd=3 , pch=20 , type="o" )
lines(crom ~a , col="#000000" ,lty=1, lwd=3 , pch=20, type="o" )
lines(resp ~a , col="#ba000d" ,lty=1, lwd=3 , pch=20 , type="o" )
lines(uri ~a , col="#607d8b" ,lty=1, lwd=3 , pch=20, type="o" )
seq(from=2015, to=2018, by=1)
axis(x, at=seq(from=2015, to=2018, by=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Para conseguir o que penso que é pedido, basta iniciar o plot com uma escala logarítmica no eixo dos `y`. E ter cuidado com os limites desse eixo.

```
plot(ost ~ a , type="o" , lty=1 , xlab="Ano" , ylab="Tipo" , 
     col=18 , lwd=3 , pch=20, xaxt ="n"
     , ylim = c(2e-1, 29)
     , log = "y"
)
```

---

Código completo, com um ciclo para traçar a sucessão de linhas após iniciar o dispositivo gráfico (*graphics device*).

```
cores <- c(snc = "#f4511e", olh = "#a1887f", card = "#bc5100", 
           fend = "#ffd95a", gen = "#00701a", dig = "#0069c0", 
           out = "#e91e63", crom = "#000000", resp = "#ba000d", 
           uri = "#607d8b")
X <- mget(names(cores), envir = .GlobalEnv)

plot(X[[1]] ~ a , type="o" , lty=1 , xlab="Ano" , ylab="Tipo" ,
     col = 18 , lwd=3 , pch=20
     , ylim = c(2e-1, 30), xaxt ="n"
     , log="y"
)
for(yname in names(X[-1])){
  y <- X[[yname]]
  lines(y ~ a, col = cores[yname], lty = 1, lwd = 3, pch = 20, type = "o")
}
axis(1, at = 2015:2018)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]